# Can not browse to directory beyond document root

Tags: linux, apache, http, permissions

This is my config for apache:

```
Listen 8180

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.100:8180>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/data
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog logs/dm-error_log

<Directory /var/www/data>
    AuthName "Protected Area"
Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /var/www/secure/passwords
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I am successfully able to get into root directory after adding +Indexes but i can not go to any folders withi root directory and I get 403 Forbidden

Answer (score 0):

If it's a permissions problem then, assuming your apache process is user=apache, you could issue a "chown -R apache /var/www/data" and restart apache.   You can issue an "ls -lRh" to see all the permissions recursively.  Also the "tree" program is a nice tool for checking hierarchies.